# Multiple IF Statements looping using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

**Data:**

This is only a sample from the data I am using.

Please find the output below. "Output via Code" is the one we are getting when we run the code. "Expected Output" is the one we are looking for.

[Data+Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPAWa.jpg)

The first code and its modified versions which I have pasted earlier seems to be giving the result but the only problem is, it is leaving one or two similar values without joining them.

**Original Message:**

I have framed a "If Statement". This statement compares two rows and displays a comment in one of the columns. While the statement works perfectly in excel, the code recorded in VBE for the same do not. Please help.

**Statement:**

```
=IF(D2=D3,(IF(G2+H2+G3+H3=0,CONCATENATE("Batch ","'",C2,"'"," has no earnings/hours"),(CONCATENATE(IF(G2=0,"",CONCATENATE("paying ","'",F2,"'"," earnings ",G2)),IF(H2=0,"",IF(H2<>0,IF(G2=0,CONCATENATE("paying ","'",F2,"'"," hours ",H2),CONCATENATE(" and hours ",H2)))),IF(G3=0,"",CONCATENATE(" , paying ","'",F3,"'"," earnings ",G3)),IF(H3=0,"",IF(H3<>0,IF(G3=0,CONCATENATE(" , paying ","'",F3,"'"," hours ",H3),CONCATENATE(" and hours ",H3)))))))),IF(D2<>D3,IF(G2+H2=0,CONCATENATE("Batch ","'",C2,"'"," has no earnings/hours"),CONCATENATE("Batch ","'",C2,"'",CONCATENATE(IF(G2=0,"",CONCATENATE(" paying ","'",F2,"'"," earnings ",G2)),IF(H2=0,"",IF(G2=0,CONCATENATE(" paying ","'",F2,"'"," hours ",H2),CONCATENATE(" and hours ",H2))))))))
```

1. I tried recording a macro for this statement, but I get a error when I execute the recorded code in my macro.
2. I would like to convert this statement into macro and run it as loop till end of last row.
3. I would like to compare a particular cell in Row 1 and Row 2, then execute above statement. Then compare values of two different cells in Row 1 and Row 2, paste the outcome in anther cell. Once these tasks are performed, delete the second row and run the loop for similar cell values, join the first comments with second comment. If next row value is different then not to delete the row and run the loop and so on till end of all rows.
4. Also, the second "if statement" isn't doing the job it is suppose to do.

**Second If Statement:**

```
=IF(D2<>D3,I2,IF(D2=D3,IF(AND(I2="Y",I3="Y"),"Y",lf(AND(I2="Y",I3="N"),"Y",IF(AND(I2="N",I3="Y"),"Y",IF(AND(I2="N",I3="N"),"N"))))))
```

VBE Code for If Statement 1:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-6]=R[1]C[-6],(IF(RC[-3]+RC[-2]+R[1]C[-3]+R[1]C[-2]=0,CONCATENATE(""Batch "",""'"",RC[-7],""'"","" has no earnings/hours""),(CONCATENATE(IF(RC[-3]=0,"""",CONCATENATE(""paying "",""'"",RC[-4],""'"","" earnings "",RC[-3])),IF(RC[-2]=0,"""",IF(RC[-2]<>0,IF(RC[-3]=0,CONCATENATE("" paying "",""'"",RC[-4],""'"",""hours"", RC[-2]),CONCATENATE("" and hours "",RC[-2]))" & _
    "1]C[-3]=0,"""",CONCATENATE("" , paying "",""'"",R[1]C[-4],""'"","" earnings "",R[1]C[-3])),(IF(R[1]C[-2]=0,"""",IF(R[1]C[-2]<>0,IF(R[1]C[-3]=0,CONCATENATE("" paying "","""",R[1]C[-4],""'"","" hours "",R[1]C[-2]),CONCATENATE("" and hours "",R[1]C[-2]))))))))),IF(RC[-6]<>R[1]C[-6],IF(RC[-3]+RC[-2]=0,CONCATENATE(""Batch "",""'"",RC[-7],""'"","" has no earnings/hours"")" & _
    "CONCATENATE(""Batch "",""'"",RC[-7],""'"",CONCATENATE(IF(RC[-3]=0,"""",CONCATENATE("" paying "",""'"",RC[-4],""'"",""earnings "",RC[-3])),IF(RC[-2]=0,"""",IF(RC[-3]=0,CONCATENATE("" paying "",""'"",RC[-4],""'"","" hours "",RC[-2]),CONCATENATE("" and hours "",RC[-2]))))))))"
```

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSEcK.jpg)

**Code 1:**

```
Sub CompareAndCompare()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
Dim A As Range, B As Range, C As Range, D As Range, E As Range, F As Range
Dim compRange As Range: Set compRange = ws.Range("D2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
Dim state1 As String

For Each A In compRange    'A = D2 on first iteration of the loop
    Set B = A.Offset(1)    'B = D3
    Set C = A.Offset(0, 3) 'C = G2
    Set D = A.Offset(0, 4) 'D = H2
    Set E = A.Offset(1, 3) 'E = G3
    Set F = A.Offset(1, 4) 'F = H3
    Set G = A.Offset(0, 5) 'G = I2
    Set H = A.Offset(1, 5) 'H = I3
    state1 = ""

    If A.Value = B.Value Then
        If G.Value = "N" And H.Value = "N" Then 'Statement 2
            ws.Range("K" & A.Row).Value = "N"
        Else
            If G.Value = "" And H.Value = "Y" Then
            ws.Range("K" & A.Row).Value = "Y"
        Else
             If G.Value = "Y" And H.Value = "" Then
            ws.Range("K" & A.Row).Value = "Y"
        Else
            If G.Value = "N" And H.Value = "" Then
            ws.Range("K" & A.Row).Value = "N"
        Else
            If G.Value = "" And H.Value = "N" Then
            ws.Range("K" & A.Row).Value = "N"
        Else
            If G.Value = "" And H.Value = "" Then
            ws.Range("K" & A.Row).Value = ""
        Else: ws.Range("K" & A.Row).Value = "Y"
        End If
       End If
      End If
     End If
    End If
  End If
        If C.Value + D.Value + E.Value + F.Value = 0 Then
            state1 = "'" & ws.Range("F" & A.Row).Value & "', " & "'" & ws.Range("F" & A.Offset(1).Row).Value & "' has no earnings/hours"
        Else
            If C.Value <> 0 Then _
                state1 = state1 & "paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Row).Value & "' earnings " & C.Value

            If D.Value <> 0 Then
                If C.Value = 0 Then
                    state1 = state1 & "paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Row).Value & "' earnings " & D.Value
                Else
                    state1 = state1 & " and hours " & D.Value
                End If
            End If

            If E.Value <> 0 Then _
                state1 = state1 & " paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Offset(1).Row).Value & "' earnings " & E.Value

            If F.Value <> 0 Then
                If E.Value = 0 Then
                    state1 = state1 & " paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Offset(1).Row).Value & "' hours " & F.Value
                Else
                    state1 = state1 & " and hours " & F.Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
        B.EntireRow.Delete
    Else 'D2 <> D3
        ws.Range("K" & A.Row).Value = G.Value 'Statement 2

        If C.Value + D.Value = 0 Then
            state1 = "'" & ws.Range("F" & A.Row).Value & "' has no earnings/hours"
        Else
            'state1 = "'" & ws.Range("F" & A.Row).Value & "'"
            If C.Value <> 0 Then _
                state1 = " paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Row) & "' earnings " & C.Value

            If D.Value <> 0 Then
                If C.Value = 0 Then
                    state1 = " paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Row) & "' hours " & D.Value
                Else
                    state1 = " and hours " & D.Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    ws.Range("J" & A.Row).Value = state1
Next A
End Sub
```

**Code 2:**

```
Sub CompareAndCompare1()
Dim ws As Worksheet:  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
Dim A As Range, B As Range
Dim compRange As Range: Set compRange = ws.Range("D2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
Dim state1 As String
For Each A In compRange    'A = D2 on first iteration of the loop
    Set B = A.Offset(1)    'B = D3
     Set C = A.Offset(0, 7) 'C =K2
    Set D = A.Offset(1, 7) 'D = K3
    state1 = ""
 If A.Value = B.Value Then
         If C.Value = "N" And D.Value = "N" Then    'Statement 2
            ws.Range("L" & A.Row).Value = "N"
        Else
            If C.Value = "" And D.Value = "Y" Then
            ws.Range("L" & A.Row).Value = "Y"
        Else
             If C.Value = "Y" And D.Value = "" Then
            ws.Range("L" & A.Row).Value = "Y"
        Else
            If C.Value = "N" And D.Value = "" Then
            ws.Range("L" & A.Row).Value = "N"
        Else
            If C.Value = "" And D.Value = "N" Then
            ws.Range("L" & A.Row).Value = "N"
        Else
            If C.Value = "" And D.Value = "" Then
            ws.Range("L" & A.Row).Value = ""
        Else: ws.Range("L" & A.Row).Value = "Y"
        End If
      End If
     End If
    End If
   End If
   End If
  state1 = "Batch " & ws.Range("C" & A.Row).Value & ": " & ws.Range("J" &  A.Row).Value & ", " & ws.Range("J" & A.Offset(1).Row).Value
 B.EntireRow.Delete 
 Else 'D2<>D3
 ws.Range("L" & A.Row).Value = C.Value
 state1 = "Batch " & ws.Range("C" & A.Row).Value & ": " & ws.Range("J" & A.Row).Value
 End If
 ws.Range("M" & A.Row).Value = state1
  Next A
  End Sub
```

**Code 3:**

```
Sub CompareAndCompare2()
Dim ws As Worksheet:  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
Dim A As Range, B As Range
Dim compRange As Range: Set compRange = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
Dim state1 As String
 For Each A In compRange    'A = A2 on first iteration of the loop
    Set B = A.Offset(1)    'B = A3
     Set C = A.Offset(0, 11) 'C =L2
    Set D = A.Offset(1, 11) 'D = L3
    state1 = ""
If A.Value = B.Value Then
        If C.Value = "N" And D.Value = "N" Then    'Statement 2
            ws.Range("N" & A.Row).Value = "N"
            Else: ws.Range("N" & A.Row).Value = "Y"
        End If
        state1 = "For file# " & ws.Range("A" & A.Row).Value & ", " &    ws.Range("M" & A.Row).Value & ", " & ws.Range("M" & A.Offset(1).Row).Value
B.EntireRow.Delete
Else 'A2<>A3
ws.Range("N" & A.Row).Value = C.Value
state1 = "For file# " & ws.Range("A" & A.Row).Value & ", " & ws.Range("M" & A.Row).Value
End If
ws.Range("O" & A.Row).Value = state1
Next A
End Sub
```

Comment: "I would like someone to write code for me" is called "Homework Help".  _3.  Questions asking for "homework help" must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._ -[Help Center: What's On Topic Here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  You haven't written any code yet...

Comment: What error did you receive when running your macro?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When I recorded the macro with the If statement  1, I got a code in VBE. When I inserted this code in my macro, it throws up "Run-time error '1004':Application-defined or object defined error". I am pasting the VBE code in original post. If Statement 2 gives :Name? error..

Comment: Where is your "ActiveCell" ? If you have your active cell in the upper left hand corner of the sheet, your references of 'negative' columns and rows will take the reference off the sheet, giving you the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Converting Formula to Macro

**I recreated a raw version of the last picture you added:**

[image]

**Using the heavily modified code below**

```
Sub CompareAndCompare()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, C As Range, D As Range, E As Range, F As Range, finalR As Range
    Dim compRange As Range: Set compRange = ws.Range("D2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
    Dim state1 As String, stateTypeA As String, yn As String, myCell As Variant
    Dim myRow As Long, STATEMENT As String, tempString() As String
    Dim passOne As Boolean, firstTime As Boolean: firstTime = True
    Dim st1 As String, st2 As String, output1 As Range, output2 As Range
    Dim idNo As Range, batchNo1 As Range, batchNo2 As Range

    For myRow = 2 To compRange.Count + 1 'This loop puts statements in "J"
        stateType = ""
StartOver:
        Set A = ws.Range("D" & myRow)        'A = D2
        Set C = ws.Range("G" & myRow)        'C = G2
        Set D = ws.Range("H" & myRow)        'D = H2
        Set output1 = ws.Range("J" & myRow)

        If A.Value = "" Then Exit For

        STATEMENT = ""
        If C.Value = 0 Then STATEMENT = STATEMENT & "1"
        If D.Value = 0 Then STATEMENT = STATEMENT & "2"
        If C.Value <> 0 Then STATEMENT = STATEMENT & "3"
        If D.Value <> 0 Then STATEMENT = STATEMENT & "4"
        stateType = "(" & ws.Range("F" & myRow).Value & ") "

        Select Case STATEMENT
            Case "12" 'C = 0, D = 0
                state1 = "*"

            Case "34" 'C <> 0, D <> 0
                state1 = stateType & "has earnings of " & C.Value & " and " & D.Value & " hours"

            Case "14" 'C = 0, D <> 0
                state1 = stateType & "has " & D.Value & " hours"

            Case "23" 'D = 0, C <> 0
                state1 = stateType & "has earnings of " & C.Value
            Case Else: MsgBox STATEMENT 'If a case isn't defined, show STATEMENT so code can be added
        End Select
            output1.Value = state1
    Next myRow
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    For myRow = 2 To compRange.Count + 1 'This Loop concatenates "J" when same "D"
Reiterate:
        Set A = ws.Range("D" & myRow) 'A = D2 on first iteration of the loop
        Set B = A.Offset(1)           'B = D3

        If A.Value = "" Then Exit For

        If A.Value = B.Value Then


CheckForMore:
            Set G = A.Offset(0, 5)        'G = I2
            Set H = A.Offset(1, 5)        'H = I3

            If (G.Value = "N" And H.Value = "N") Or ((G.Value = "" Or H.Value = "") And (G.Value = "N" Or H.Value = "N")) Then 'Statement 2
                yn = "N"
            Else: yn = "Y"
            End If

            ws.Range("K" & myRow).Value = yn
            Set B = A.Offset(1)
            st1 = "(" & ws.Range("F" & myRow).Value & ")"
            st2 = "(" & ws.Range("F" & myRow + 1).Value & ")"
            Set output1 = ws.Range("J" & myRow)
            Set output2 = ws.Range("J" & myRow + 1)

            If firstTime = True Then
                If output1.Value = "*" Then
                    firstTime = False
                    stateType = st1
                End If
            End If

            If output2.Value = "*" And A.Value = B.Value Then
                If stateType = "" Then
                    stateType = st2
                Else: stateType = stateType & ", " & st2
                End If
                B.EntireRow.Delete
                GoTo CheckForMore

            ElseIf output1.Value = "*" And firstTime = False And A.Value = B.Value Then
                output1.Value = "* have no earnings/hours, " & output2.Value
                B.EntireRow.Delete
                GoTo Reiterate

            ElseIf output1.Value <> "*" And firstTime = False And A.Value = B.Value Then
                output1.Value = output1.Value & ", " & output2.Value
                B.EntireRow.Delete
                GoTo Reiterate

            ElseIf output1.Value <> "*" And stateType <> "" And A.Value = B.Value Then
                output1.Value = output1.Value & ", * have no earnings/hours, " & output2.Value
                B.EntireRow.Delete
                GoTo Reiterate '''''''''''''''''''''''

            ElseIf output1.Value = "*" And A.Value <> B.Value Then
                output1.Value = "* have no earnings/hours "

            ElseIf output1.Value <> "*" And stateType <> "" Then
                output1.Value = output1.Value & ", * have no earnings/hours "
            End If

            output1.Value = Replace(output1.Value, "*", stateType)
            firstTime = True
            stateType = ""
        Else
            output1.Value = Replace(output1.Value, "*", stateType)
            firstTime = True
            stateType = ""
        End If
    Next myRow

    Set finalR = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    passOne = False
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    For Each myCell In finalR 'This loop finalizes and removes duplicates
        myRow = myCell.Row
finalAgain:
        Set output1 = ws.Range("J" & myRow)
        Set output2 = ws.Range("J" & myRow + 1)
        Set idNo = ws.Range("A" & myRow)
        Set batchNo1 = ws.Range("C" & myRow)
        Set batchNo2 = ws.Range("C" & myRow + 1)

        If myCell.Value = myCell.Offset(1).Value Then
            If passOne = False Then
                output1.Value = "FOR " & idNo.Value & ", FROM BATCH " & batchNo1.Value & ": " & output1.Value _
                    & Chr(10) & "FROM BATCH " & batchNo2.Value & ": " & output2.Value
            Else: output1.Value = output1.Value & Chr(10) & "FROM BATCH " & batchNo2.Value & ": " & output2.Value
            End If
            myCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
            passOne = True
            GoTo finalAgain
        Else: If passOne = False Then output1.Value = "FOR " & idNo.Value & ", FROM BATCH " & batchNo1.Value & ": " & output1.Value
        End If
        passOne = False
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

**Will yield the following result:**

[image]

***Which looks similar to what you were wanting. I made some edit to the formatting to make it easier to read. Let me know what you think and if this works for you :)***

---

---

### Original Answer Below (May be useful in seeing how to convert EXCEL Formula into VBA Code)

**I'm not sure I understand the scope of your question but this is the direct conversion as best as I could make sense of it. Let me know if it functions how you imagine it should.**

---

**I recreated your sheet:**

[image]

---

**The first thing you want to do when doing a conversion like this is to break your formula up into a proper code format. I included `Else` and `End if/conc` lines to make your end parentheses easier to follow:**

**STATEMENT 1**

```
----------------------------STATEMENT 1-----------------------------
IF(D2=D3,
    (IF(G2+H2+G3+H3=0,
        CONCATENATE("Batch ","'",C2,"'"," has no earnings/hours"),
    Else
        (CONCATENATE(
            IF(G2=0,
                "",
            Else
                CONCATENATE("paying ","'",F2,"'"," earnings ",G2)
            end if),
            IF(H2=0,
                "",
            Else
                IF(H2<>0,
                    IF(G2=0,
                        CONCATENATE("paying ","'",F2,"'"," hours ",H2),
                    Else
                        CONCATENATE(" and hours ",H2)
                    end if)
                end if)
            end if),
            IF(G3=0,
                "",
            Else
                CONCATENATE(" , paying ","'",F3,"'"," earnings ",G3)
            end if),
            IF(H3=0,
                "",
            Else
                IF(H3<>0,
                    IF(G3=0,
                        CONCATENATE(" , paying ","'",F3,"'"," hours ",H3),
                    Else
                        CONCATENATE(" and hours ",H3)
                    end if)
                end if)
            end if)
        end concatenate))
    end if))
    IF(D2<>D3,
        IF(G2+H2=0,
            CONCATENATE("Batch ","'",C2,"'"," has no earnings/hours"),
        Else
            CONCATENATE("Batch ","'",C2,"'",
                CONCATENATE(
                    IF(G2=0,
                        "",
                    Else
                        CONCATENATE(" paying ","'",F2,"'"," earnings ",G2)
                    end if),
                    IF(H2=0,
                        "",
                    Else
                        IF(G2=0,
                            CONCATENATE(" paying ","'",F2,"'"," hours ",H2),
                        Else
                            CONCATENATE(" and hours ",H2)
                        end if)
                    end if)
                end concatenate)
            end concatenate)
        end if)
    end if)
end if)
```

**STATEMENT 2**

```
----------------------------STATEMENT 2-----------------------------
=IF(D2<>D3,
    I2,
Else
    IF(D2=D3,
        IF(AND(I2="Y",I3="Y"),
            "Y",
        Else
            IF(AND(I2="Y",I3="N"),
                "Y",
            Else
                IF(AND(I2="N",I3="Y"),
                    "Y",
                Else
                    IF(AND(I2="N",I3="N"),
                        "N"
                    end if)
                end if)
            end if)
        end if)
    end if)
end if)
```

---

**With this easy to read format, it's just a matter of using proper VBA vocabulary and a little clean up**

```
Sub CompareAndCompare()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, C As Range, D As Range, E As Range, F As Range
    Dim compRange As Range: Set compRange = ws.Range("D2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
    Dim state1 As String

    For Each A In compRange    'A = D2 on first iteration of the loop
        Set B = A.Offset(1)    'B = D3
        Set C = A.Offset(0, 3) 'C = G2
        Set D = A.Offset(0, 4) 'D = H2
        Set E = A.Offset(1, 3) 'E = G3
        Set F = A.Offset(1, 4) 'F = H3
        Set G = A.Offset(0, 5) 'G = I2
        Set H = A.Offset(1, 5) 'H = I3
        state1 = ""

        If A.Value = B.Value Then
            If G.Value = "N" And H.Value = "N" Then 'Statement 2
                ws.Range("K" & A.Row).Value = "N"
            Else: ws.Range("K" & A.Row).Value = "Y"
            End If

            If C.Value + D.Value + E.Value + F.Value = 0 Then
                state1 = "Batch '" & ws.Range("C" & A.Row).Value & "' has no earnings/hours"
            Else
                If C.Value <> 0 Then _
                    state1 = state1 & "paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Row).Value & "' earnings " & C.Value

                If D.Value <> 0 Then
                    If C.Value = 0 Then
                        state1 = state1 & "paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Row).Value & "' earnings " & D.Value
                    Else
                        state1 = state1 & " and hours " & D.Value
                    End If
                End If

                If E.Value <> 0 Then _
                    state1 = state1 & " , paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Offset(1).Row).Value & "' earnings " & E.Value

                If F.Value <> 0 Then
                    If E.Value = 0 Then
                        state1 = state1 & " , paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Offset(1).Row).Value & "' hours " & F.Value
                    Else
                        state1 = state1 & " and hours " & F.Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            B.EntireRow.Delete
        Else 'D2 <> D3
            ws.Range("K" & A.Row).Value = G.Value 'Statement 2

            If C.Value + D.Value = 0 Then
                state1 = "Batch '" & ws.Range("C" & A.Row).Value & "' has no earnings/hours"
            Else
                state1 = "Batch '" & ws.Range("C" & A.Row).Value & "'"
                If C.Value <> 0 Then _
                    state1 = state1 & " paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Row) & "' earnings " & C.Value

                If D.Value <> 0 Then
                    If C.Value = 0 Then
                        state1 = state1 & " paying '" & ws.Range("F" & A.Row) & "' hours " & D.Value
                    Else
                        state1 = state1 & " and hours " & D.Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        ws.Range("J" & A.Row).Value = state1
    Next A
End Sub
```

---

**When I run this code on the sheet, this is the resulting output:**

[image]

---

It deleted the rows when D2:D3 are the same, and continues through the rest of the items in that range (which is dynamic). I didn't change the statements you wanted on the output. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I'm thinking you're going to want the first row deleted because D2 = D3 still. That's easy enough to do, it just depends on where you have the `B.EntireRow.Delete` line. Either at the start, or at the end. Currently it's at the end, unless you want me to put it at the beginning :)

Comment: Tyeler, Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. I am new at  VBA and still learning it. The output seems to be promising. Yes, D 2 and D3 are still same, the comments in J2 and J3 should add and one of the rows should be deleted. This should happen for entire range i.e. comments for similar ids should join and for non similar, it should remain the same. This should continue till end of the range. a

Comment: I know, I am asking for too much, but can we also include or add this to If Statement 2: if(AND(I2="",I3="Y"),"Y" else if(AND(I2="Y",I3=""),"Y" else if(AND(I2="N",I3=""),"N" else if(AND(I2="N",I3=""),"N","")endif)endif)..

Comment: No problem, gimme just a sec and I'll fix it up for you. :)

Comment: Actually, from what you said in your first comment, the first row is going to have this output in J2: `Batch 'ABC' has no earnings/hoursBatch 'ABC' paying 'S' earnings 2697.62` Is that really what you want it to look like?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have modified the comments a little. Actually the output would look something like this 'x' , 's' has no earning/hours, paying 'S' earnings 2697.62. Once this is done, I will have to re-run the loop but this time compare first column A1=A2 then join J1 and J2. Then the entire comments would look something like this, For '123', batch 'ABC', 'x','s' has no earnings, paying 's' earnings 2697.62, batch 'XYZ', 'O' has no earnings (if there are any earnings/ hours then 'O' has hours 20) with same condition for statement 2. Finally, I will get a o/p without repetition

Comment: Can take your spreadsheet and show a complicated deletion, concatenate, resulting in the final product for one row? Like background color the rows that would be deleted in red or something, and show how their values would get concatenated. I think I'd be able to understand the scope a little better this way. Make it where after all is said and done, 4 lines turn into 1 with something being added from each of the 3 lines to the last remaining one. post this as a picture in the bottom of your question and comment here when you're done so i get the alert. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I have made the sheet that you have asked for. I hope you would understand the output I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. In final output, comparison would be between A1 and A2 from output 1 and their consecutive comments would be concatenated with few more additional comments. Also, "Y" and "N" would be compared from new column in output 1 for A1 and A2 and result would be pasted in final output. Thanks..

Comment: I have new code written and its almost done but duty calls at work so if you dont mind waiting until later today, ill be able to get the updated answer for you. I used a different method too, so ill teach you how it works and why i changed it. :)

Comment: Thank you so much Tyeler. I have really learnt something from you. I used your coce and made some modifications to it to run it again and again to get the final output. I did get the final output but there are still few rows with similar values that did not join. I would be waiting for your new code and would be learning even more. I am pasting the codes that I have modified using your code above in original message.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you, but I finally finished it. It's at the top of my answer. I believe it's exactly what you were originally trying to achieve. Let me know what you think of it :)

Comment: Hey Tyeler, I tried your new code and I'm sorry to say that it isn't working like it should. Also, the statement 2 "Y" and "N" isn't giving desired result. I have added an image to the main question which shows the sample data and output vs expected data.

Comment: I think if we can figure out how to run the loop without skipping the similar cell in Code 2 can fix the issue once and for all. I ran the code 2 in debug mode and see that it is comparing Row1 and Row2, adding the comments, deleting Row2. Now Row 3 becomes Row1 instead of Row1 being Row1 and comparing itself with Row3(which is new Row2) and if they are same add the comments else move on to Row 3(new Row2) and compare it with Row4(new Row3) and so on..

Comment: Did you mean to remove the original Column D data (used to have `123-ACB` in it and such). Because the code was using that column.

Comment: No, that would still be intact till we receive the final output. Once, we have got the result we want, we can leave the column or delete it at the end. I ran the code with and without that column - With column D, I am getting the result shown in the image. without Column D, I get something with lot of data missing in it. For now lets assume we keep the column D as it is and get the final output with comments mentioned in expected result.

Comment: Hey Teyler, is there a way to reset the counter in code 3, for each condition because it will solve the problem. Now what happens is whenever the loop runs, it adds two similar values, deletes the second value an and loop runs again from 3rd value. In this case, we get two values of same group. If the loop stops starts again at 1st value and compares with 3rd value after deleting 2nd value and if there's no similar value then moves to next row, my problem would be solved. Waiting for your response.

Comment: I just fixed the code. Gimme one sec, I'm posting it now. It works 100% in accordance with the last data set you gave me. I also improved further on the formatting.

Comment: Answer updated. Let me know what you think. That was actually a lot more difficult to figure out the logic than I thought it would be...

Comment: I gotta go, might be for the night. If anything comes up, I won't be able to get to it until tomorrow night. Hope it meets your needs this time! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for all you support Tyeler. I will try your code once I am back in office and keep you updated. I have my fingers crossed and hoping that it works so that I don't give you any more trouble. You have been really helpful.

Comment: Hey Tyeler, I have tried your new code today. I have no words to say, it is working like a charm. You made my day today. I have finished that project and results are outstanding. Thank you so much for your help.. :D

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, could you mark my answer as the answer to your question? I'm glad I could help you :)

Comment: Hey Tyeler, I lready did that, but I do not have enough reputations so it is not considering my vote

Comment: No, not upvote, although I do appreciate that. There's a check mark under the up/down vote icon. If you click the check mark, you'll accept this answer as the answer. :)